# how to resize popupmenu

Tags: android, user-interface, popupwindow

i create a quick action. but occured with a problem in set height of quick action.
my quicck action is a popup menu that contain views. you can see its picture below:

[image]

i click on the buuton. then quick action appeard. oh, quick action is bigger than real space (available spavce). then i resize it. it's ok.
but please see it in new image:

[image]

similar previus quick action is bigger than real space. then i resize it. but resize result is not things i desired. it goes on the anchor. where is problem. i resize it with following command
`mypopupwindow.setHeight(realSpace)`

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: no. i dont work on this. but why you sat this?